# Make a log file with php

Tags: php, mysql

My register page looks like this

```
$checkForUser = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `users` WHERE `username`='{$posts['username']}' OR `email`='{$posts['email']}'");
$checkForUserRows = mysql_num_rows($checkForUser);

$ip = VisitorIP();
$checkForIP = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `users` WHERE `ip`='{$ip}'");
$checkForIPRows = mysql_num_rows($checkForIP);

if ($checkForUserRows > 0) {
    $error = "Username or email already registered!";
}else if ($checkForIPRows > 0)  {
    $error = "You may only have one account! This attempt has been logged. You will be banned! ";
```

I want to auto ban the account whose ip is already exists, with following error `$error = "You may only have one account! This attempt has been logged. You will be banned! ";`

Comment: And what's the problem? What error do you get, or what do you see happening? (Note that you're using insecure code that can get hacked, plus you're using soon-to-be-depreciated functions. As opposed to using mysql_() functions, please check PDO and/or mysqli_() functions in the manual.)

Answer (score 0):

Just write a log file with fwrite http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

To ban the ip, you need to do an ip check at the beginning of the code. You should probably add a bool column to the database "banned".